# Desactivar boton con ng-disabled Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Tengo un `select` donde selecciono el `tipo` de archivo que voy a enviar si es `pdf` o `img`, en caso de que sea `img` le debo enviar `image-A` y `image-B` apenas envié las 2 `imgs` se debe desactivar el `boton` de enviar, ahora solo desactiva cuando envió 1 `img` pero necesito enviar primero las 2 y luego desactivar el `boton`
 Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.btnActivePdf = false;
    $scope.btnActiveImg1 = false;
    $scope.btnActiveImg2 = false;
    $scope.uploadFile = function(paramFile) {
        if (paramFile === 'pdf') {
            $scope.btnActivePdf = true;
        }
        if (paramFile === 'image-A') {
            $scope.btnActiveImg1 = true;
        }
        if (paramFile === 'image-A') {
            $scope.btnActiveImg2 = true;
        }

    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html charsfet>
    <head>
<!--CDN ANGULARJS -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        button[disabled] {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <select ng-model="typeFile">
            <option value="img">Imagen</option>
            <option value="pdf">Pdf</option>
        </select>
        <div>
            <div ng-show="typeFile == 'pdf'">
                <button type="button" ng-click="uploadFile('pdf')">Cargar pdf</button>
            </div>
            <div ng-show="typeFile == 'img'">
                <button type="button" ng-click="uploadFile('image-A')">Cargar img1</button>
                <button type="button" ng-click="uploadFile('image-B')">Cargar img2</button>
            </div>
            <button ng-disabled="btnActivePdf || btnActiveImg1 && btnActiveImg2">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

En el segundo `if` de las imagenes tienes que comprobar image-B.
Por si acaso he incluido parentesis en el `AND` del disabled del boton de enviar.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.btnActivePdf = false;
    $scope.btnActiveImg1 = false;
    $scope.btnActiveImg2 = false;
    $scope.uploadFile = function(paramFile) {
    $scope.btnActivePdf = paramFile === 'pdf';

        if (paramFile === 'image-A') {
            $scope.btnActiveImg1 = true;
        }
        if (paramFile === 'image-B') {
            $scope.btnActiveImg2 = true;
        }

    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html charsfet>
    <head>
<!--CDN ANGULARJS -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        button[disabled] {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <select ng-model="typeFile">
            <option value="img">Imagen</option>
            <option value="pdf">Pdf</option>
        </select>
        <div>
            <div ng-show="typeFile == 'pdf'">
                <button type="button" ng-click="uploadFile('pdf')">Cargar pdf</button>
            </div>
            <div ng-show="typeFile == 'img'">
                <button type="button" ng-click="uploadFile('image-A')">Cargar img1</button>
                <button type="button" ng-click="uploadFile('image-B')">Cargar img2</button>
            </div>
            <button ng-disabled="btnActivePdf || (btnActiveImg1 && btnActiveImg2)">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: no existe una manera de hacerlo mas facil? sin hacer 3 IF

Comment: @TheVicious Esto es lo mejor que se me ocurre ahora mismo.

Comment: ok listo muchas gracias por tu respuesta, con esto ya me hago una idea de lo que necesito.

Comment: @TheVicious Si la respuesta es correcta, marcala por favor.